# What's the relationship between Ethereum and Filecoin?

Tags: altcoin

I read on a few websites that Filecoin will "run" on Ethereum. Is that still the plan for Filecoin? If so, what does this mean in practice?

Answer (score 1):

Filecoin has its own blockchain network running on top of [IPFS](https://ipfs.io/). Unlike IPFS, filecoin is incentivized with the native token called  Filecoin.

Comment: I don't think your comment answers the question about the reported usage of Etherium.

Answer (score 0):

Filecoin uses FEVM to run its contracts. The really cool stuff about it is that the name itself has Ethereum (F**E**VM) in it.

The plus point  is that a public-private key pair or address on the Ethereum network can still remain the **same** on the Filecoin network and they have made it so easy to use that anyone who has knowledge of the Ethereum network, can quickly work his/her way around.

**Important to note that: Filecoin isn't running on EVM but it is EVM compatible**

> Filecoin has a virtual machine which can run an Ethereum
> network-like contracts and transactions on its virtual machine.

I hope this answers your query! ✌